# What is the meaning of equation of a circle or equation of a cube?

Tags: geometry, circles

We have an equation of a Circle $$x^2 + y^2 = 1$$ and equation of a Cube $${||x-y|+|x+y|-2z|+||x-y|+|x+y|+2z|=1}$$

When I substitute x,y in first equation or x,y,z in the second equation then the equations are said to be satisfied when LHS and RHS are equal.

I have a quick question. If the first equation or second equation get satisfied, because LHS becomes equal to RHS, then those values of x and y of first equation are said to be lying on the circumference of the circle and not inside or outside of the circle and x,y,z of the second equation are said to be lying on the surface of the cube and not on the inside and not on the circle of the cube. Correct?

[image: Equation]

Comment: Yes. The $(x,y)$ satisfying $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is the unit circle. The inside of the circle would be given by $x^2 + y^2 < 1$ and the outside $x^2 + y^2 > 1$.

Comment: Yes, your words are essentially correct. The solutions to each equation fill the geometric objects specified. I do not understand the picture.

Comment: Yes the equations given outline the diagram or as in the second case, the structure

Comment: See also [Wikipedia: Analytic Geometry: Equations and curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_geometry#Equations_and_curves)

Comment: You just edited the question to add the paragraph about "creating" these figures. That doesn't make mathematical sense. I think you already have two correct answers to the original question. Consider accepting one of them, perhaps upvoting both.

Comment: I just reverted back to the previous version of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In set-builder notation, one would say the following

The circle $S$ consists of of
$$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2+y^2=1\}.$$

And same goes for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is what those equations mean.

In general, a relation defined by an equation is graphed as the set of all points that satisfy the given equation. So exactly the same as you would graph a line, a parabola, or non-function relations like these two. In fact, disregarding the visual side of things, some people refer to the *concept* of the set of points satisfying the equations as the graph of the given object.

To find all the points inside the circle, you could use an inequality like

$$ x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 $$